# Postgres Schema Design for School Classes with Cancellations and Substitute Instructors

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have modelled a series of school classes as follows. 
The part I am not sure about is having a separate table for cancellations and substitute instructors.

With this setup every time you looked up the class schedule for a given week you would have to search the `class_exceptions` table in order to 
see if the class was cancelled or the instructor was substituted with another one.

Is there a better way of modelling this schema?

````sql
CREATE TABLE staff (
 email TEXT,
 created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
 updated_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
 PRIMARY KEY (email)
);

CREATE TABLE class_types (
  id bigserial,
  name text NOT NULL,
  instructor_email TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (instructor_email) REFERENCES staff (email),
  created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
  updated_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE classes (
  class_type_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  recurs_weekly BOOLEAN,
  is_public BOOLEAN,
  start_timestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  end_timestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
  FOREIGN KEY (class_type_id) REFERENCES class_types (id),
  PRIMARY KEY (class_type_id, start_timestamp)
);


CREATE TABLE class_exceptions (
  is_cancelled BOOLEAN,
  class_type_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  start_timestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  cover_instructor_email TEXT,
  FOREIGN KEY (class_type_id, start_timestamp) REFERENCES classes(class_type_id, start_timestamp),
  FOREIGN KEY (cover_instructor_email) REFERENCES staff (email),
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL default (now() at time zone 'utc'),
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL default (now() at time zone 'utc')
);
```
````